# In Angular how do I dynamically wrap certain words in another html element?

Tags: html, angular, components, angular-components

I have this simple Angular Component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  template: '<p>{{someString}}</p>',
})
export class MyComponent  {
  @Input() someString: string;
}
```

`someString` could be any string of any length. As an example, imagine that `someString`'s value is :

```
"If you want my body and you think I'm sexy, come on, sugar, tell me so."
```

In that case the HTML generated by Angular would essentially be equivalent to:

```html
<p>If you want my body and you think I'm sexy, come on, sugar, tell me so.</p>
```

How would I modify `MyComponent` so that it detects each occurrence of the word `sexy` in `someString` and have Angular wrap that word in another HTML element such as `<b>`. So in this example case it would generate something like:

```html
<p>If you want my body and you think I'm <b>sexy</b>, come on, sugar, tell me so.</p>
```

What if I wanted to wrap every occurrence of the word `sexy` in an Angular Component instead of a native HTML Element? Would that necessitate a different approach?

Comment: You can search for the word in the sentence and then inject the opening and closing tag before and after it respectively.

Comment: @NicholasK And how do I inject the opening and closing tags?

Comment: I added an answer, moreorless the same as the other answer. (IMO, the other one is better!) Deleted mine, as it was way too compilcated..

Comment: Hi - I've done what you're asking re: wrapping in another angular tag.  It was pretty bleugh.  I eventually had to export the angular component I was trying wrap text in (in this case <tag></tag>) as a native element first.   Find another way round the problem would be my advice.  E.g. add an (click) event handler to the top element, and see if it's one of the <b> tags you've wrapped it in, then do something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution avoids using `innerHTML` and relies strictly on Angular constructs.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  template: `
  <p>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let segment of segments">
      <span *ngIf="!segment.shouldBeBold()">segment.text</span>
      <b *ngIf="segment.shouldBeBold()">segment.text</b>
    </ng-container>
  </p>
  `,
})
export class MyComponent  {
  @Input() someString: string;

  private wordsToBold = new Set(['sexy', 'body', 'sugar']); 

  get segments() {
    const regex = this.makeRegex();
    const segments = this.someString.split(regex);
    return segments.map(segment => {
      return { text: segment, shouldBeBold: wordsToBold.has(segment.toLowerCase()) };
    });
  }

  private makeRegex() {
    const expression = [...this.wordsToBold].join('\\b|\\b');
    return new RegExp(`(\\b${expression}\\b)+`, 'gi');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try this :D

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-test',
  template: `
    <p [innerHTML]="stringFormatted()"></p>
  `,
  styles: []
})
export class TestComponent {

  someString = "If you want my body and you think I'm sexy, come on, sugar, tell me so.";

  stringFormatted() {
    return this.someString.replace(/sexy/g, '<b>sexy</b>');
  }
}
```

Comment: I thought modifying innerHTML in that way was kind of frowned upon when using a framework like Angular? Am I mistaken?

Comment: For me this is the easiest way to achieve your requirement.

Comment: Really I'm not sure if are a better way to do it. If the string is loaded from an external source you should pass it through a DOMsanitizer, but i think there is no problem using it.

Comment: @snowfrogdev : You can read up on [DOM Sanitization](https://angular.io/guide/security#sanitization-and-security-contexts) to make sure nothing malicious gets injected.

Comment: So I'm guessing that this solution wouldn't work in the case where instead of wrapping the word in <b> I would want to wrap it in my own Angular Component?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the something like below - wherein after rendering the main sentence, you can replace the special word with a span element and apply a CSS class, say `.special` to that span tag.

import { Component, Input, ElementRef, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  template: '<p>{{sentence}}</p>'
})
export class MyComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @Input() sentence: string;
  @Input() specialWord: string;

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.el.nativeElement.innerHTML = this.el.nativeElement.
      innerHTML.replace(new RegExp(`${this.specialWord}`, 'g'), 
          `<span class="special">${this.specialWord}</span>`);
  }
}
```

To keep your code generic, you can use additional `@Input()` for special word.

In your application's `styles.scss`, you can define the CSS class `.special`.

```
.special {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

If you wonder why you can't use similar logic to replace the content of `sentence` by something like below:

```
    this.sentence = this.sentence.replace(new RegExp(`${this.specialWord}`, 'g'),
         `<span class="special">${this.specialWord}</span>`);
```

then, note that Angular will escape the HTML tags and they will appear as is in the output.  So you will see something like this in the browser, instead of styled spans.

```
Hello, it's a <span class="special">beautiful</span> day and I am in a very <span class="special">beautiful</span> city
```

That's why, I had to resort to manipulating the `innerHTML` so that replacement is done after Angular has rendered the sentence to DOM.

Comment: I thought modifying innerHTML in that way was kind of frowned upon when using a framework like Angular? Am I mistaken?

Comment: Your problem is also peculiar and I am not sure whether there is any other way to achieve it.

Comment: @snowfrogdev it does, but it's largely okay with simple html. To do more you need to use sanitizeDom https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer

Comment: So I'm guessing that this solution wouldn't work in the case where instead of wrapping the word in <b> I would want to wrap it in my own Angular Component?