# Segment string sequentially using Regex in typescript

Tags: javascript, regex, typescript, string, split

I am following the accepted answer found here: [In Angular how do I dynamically wrap certain words in another html element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60342996/in-angular-how-do-i-dynamically-wrap-certain-words-in-another-html-element)

The TL;DR of the question is that in a string, certain words from a set `this.wordsToBold` need to be segmented into an array using Regex. So if the set has the word `"test"` and the string is `"hi this is a test string"` the segments are `["hi this is a ", "test", " string"]`.

In it they use a `\b` to match words, I modified the answer so it can work with substrings regardless if there is whitespace between the word trying to be identified:

Code Example (My current solution):

https://playcode.io/948321

The problem with my Regex expression is that it seems to leave out words that are together and in the set. For example:
`this.wordsToBold=["foo", "bar"]` the string is `Thisfoo is a foobar sentence bar` would return segments like: `["This", "foo", " is a " "foo", " sentence ", "bar"]`.

Is there a way to modify my Regex expression so that the first "bar" is not lost?
Thanks!

Comment: Your regex making code creates an invalid regex. Try `return new RegExp("(" + expression.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&') + ")", 'i');`, `g` flag is unnecessary in `.split`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, Hi thanks for the tip, I tried it but the string no longer segments.

Comment: Please provide a working example, a fiddle on codepen, or jsfiddle would be great.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Hi, I've updated the question with a link that has an example of my solution running.

Comment: Ok, so what if you remove `+`? Try ``return new RegExp(`(${expression})`, 'gi');``

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```js
return new RegExp(`(${expression.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&')})`, 'gi');
```

That is

- Escape the `expression`, unless it is a valid regex.
- Remove the `+` at the end, since it creates a repeated capturing group and only the last sequence captured remains in the final result.

Comment: Your answer of `return new RegExp(`(${expression})`, 'gi');`  Is what worked for me.